# ROSRUN IMAGE_VIEW problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody
I am trying to remotely see the image from a usb camera installed on a robot.
I run the command

> rosrun image_view image_view image:=/logitech_usb_cam/image_raw

and I get this feedback
(image_raw:3417): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

What does this mean?
Thank you all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44217/rosrun-image_view-problem/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be a general bug in ubuntu 11.10. Take a view on

http://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line

---

Originally posted by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) with karma: 427 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1